# Check if word alternates consonant and vowel

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

So I need to check if a word is a pattern of alternating vowel and cosonant (Or consonant and vowel) in Java.

I want to make it a regex but I just came with this incomplete regex expression:

```
[aeiouAEIOI][^aeiouAEIOI]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks :)

Update: It's not regex restricted, so it can be an option if anyone has any ideas

Comment: Does it have to be a regex?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: You can use the following website https://regex101.com/ to test your regular expression directly in java and even generate some code. I think your regex looks fine, the only problem it still has is that it does not take into account that you can have a single or multiple occurences of your pattern. Take a look at the quick reference (bottom right). There is a section called quantifiers that should provide some guidance to you.

Answer (score 2):

One way is using a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if neither two vowels nor two consonants next to each other.

```
(?i)^(?!.*?(?:[aeiou]{2}|[^aeiou]{2}))[a-z]+$
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PAS5La/2) (used `i` [flag](https://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) for *caseless* matching, the `\n` in demo is for staying in line)

---

*Update*: Thank you for the comment @Thefourthbird. For matching at least two characters you will need to change the last [quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/refrepeat.html): Use [`[a-z]{2,}`](https://regex101.com/r/AMMZME/1) (*two or more*) instead of `[a-z]+` (*one or more*). For only matching an *even amount* of characters (2,4,6,8...), change this part to: [`(?:[a-z]{2})+`](https://regex101.com/r/e6fosy/1)

---

*FYI*: If you use this with [`matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) you can drop the `^` *start* and `$` *end* anchor (see [this Java demo](https://tio.run/##PYyxDoIwGIT3PkXt1GLo4CgDiYlPwNhg8gMNFlsg9C9BkWdHxMRb7nL57hoYIW6qx7oa13cD0mYrZEBj5aBrPckoIaS04D29TuB6q8lM6KY@FNaU1CPgZmNnKurAtDzDwbS1yikMtRc7@ht8lT09aie7gLLfMLQtZxcoSiYdYHnXnjOeGsHTg4xSnp4VaNOFfD4tb3X7ZyEUxK/8yIRI9uuFLOv6AQ)).

Comment: I think if you want to be sure that there is a `consonant and vowel` the repetition of the last character class can be `[a-z]{2,}` or a [repeating of 2 chars](https://regex101.com/r/e6fosy/1)..but I am not sure. I will remove the comment soon.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thank you, yes. In my understanding it would also match a single character maybe only OP knows that, upvoting your comment if this is wanted.